# AngelList API - startup ids

Tags: java

I am a developer and I’d would like to know if the startups ids are available somewhere for developers that need to use the AngelList API.

Can someone please help me?

This is my code:

```
int f = 1;
// Reading Json data from Rest API and paginating it.
for(int h = 1000; h<=10000; h++){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("Start downloading pages from AngelList..");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    String URL = "https://api.angel.co/1/startups/" + h;
    InputStream in = null;
    try{
        in = URI.create(URL).toURL().openStream();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        Date date2 = new Date();
        System.out.println("Begin: " + dateFormat.format(date) + " Now: "+ dateFormat.format(date2));
        System.out.println("I've done 1000 requests, wait 60 min...");
        h--;
        in = null;
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(60);
    }
    if(in!=null){
        // writing each page into a separate file if in is not null
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(
                "/my-path/file" + f + ".txt");
        f++;
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        fout.close();
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I would know the ids because at present time i've chose that random (1000 - 10000).

Comment: Have you tried looking at the API documentation for the AngelList API? There's a search option in there.

Comment: Now I'm trying this way. Thank you for the suggest.

Comment: Note: i have to know anyway the name of the startup i'm looking for.

Comment: @SerenaSforza did you find the answer? I am trying to get the same.